# Pool that seems to be stuck on a block

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin

I'm running a Litecoin pool that seems like it might be stuck on a particular block... it's been working fine all along but is currently at like 312% Of Expected Shares, I've checked the cron jobs and they seem to be running fine (none disabled) ... should I take action on this or is it purely a bad luck situation?

Comment: Have you tried running a block count on your pool and comparing it to a litecoin block explorer?

Comment: well when I do a getinfo command it appears that the blocks I have match up with what is currently on the block chain... if that's what you mean

Comment: 3x difficulty is nothing unusual

Comment: Since `exp(-3.12)` is about 0.044, you normally should expect a pool to exceed 312% of expected shares on about 4.4% of all blocks.  So as @Dr.Haribo says, this wouldn't be unusual.

Comment: thank you for the replies.  maybe I'll get lucky on the block today!

Comment: so a follow-up on this question, what would be some signs of an issue impending or that has already happened?